# How to avoid interpolation of sensitive variables in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a variable in environment something like this

```
        PACT_ARGUMENTS = "--pacticipant ${APP_NAME} \
                    --broker-base-url ${PACT_BROKER_URL} \
                    --broker-username ${PACT_BROKER_BASIC_CREDENTIALS_USR} \
                    --broker-password ${PACT_BROKER_BASIC_CREDENTIALS_PSW} \
                    --version ${GIT_COMMIT}"
```

I have two stages where I use them like this

```
stage('Can I Deploy to Dev') {
        agent none
        steps {
            sh 'docker run --rm ${PACT_CLI_IMAGE} broker can-i-deploy ${PACT_ARGUMENTS} --to ${PACT_DEFAULT_ENV}'
        }
    }

       stage('Create Dev Version Tag') {
        agent none
        steps {
            sh 'docker run --rm ${PACT_CLI_IMAGE} broker create-version-tag ${PACT_ARGUMENTS} --tag ${PACT_DEFAULT_ENV}'
        }
    }
```

It works fine but I am getting notifications in Jenkins saying that **The following steps that have been detected may have insecure interpolation of sensitive variables**

The solution that I used to have is

```
stage('Can I Deploy to Dev') {
    agent none
    steps {
        sh 'docker run --rm ${PACT_CLI_IMAGE} broker can-i-deploy \
                --pacticipant ${APP_NAME} \
                --broker-base-url ${PACT_BROKER_URL} \
                --broker-username ${PACT_BROKER_BASIC_CREDENTIALS_USR} \
                --broker-password ${PACT_BROKER_BASIC_CREDENTIALS_PSW} \
                --version ${GIT_COMMIT}\
                --to ${PACT_DEFAULT_ENV}'
    }
}
```

but I chose to extract few of those arguments because it would be look a bit cleaner. I tried to replace PACT_ARGUMENTS with single quote but it just take the whole thing as a string. Any suggestions how to handle this scenario?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in order to be able to use expressions like ${variable} as part of a String is to use double quotes when you declare that String. If you use single quotes, they won't be replaced.

Comment: use single quotes for PACT_ARGUMENTS but double-quotes for `sh`. the idea to pass password variable through environment variable (like in your solution) and not through interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @daggett suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308617/how-to-avoid-interpolation-of-sensitive-variables-in-jenkins?noredirect=1#comment118973894_67308617)

I replace double quotes to single quotes to PACT_ARGUMENTS variable like this

```
        PACT_ARGUMENTS = '--pacticipant $APP_NAME \
                    --broker-base-url $PACT_BROKER_URL \
                    --broker-username $PACT_BROKER_BASIC_CREDENTIALS_USR \
                    --broker-password $PACT_BROKER_BASIC_CREDENTIALS_PSW \
                    --version $GIT_COMMIT'
```

Then I used double quotes for `sh` like this

```
        stage('Can I Deploy to Dev') {
        agent none
        steps {
            sh "docker run --rm ${PACT_CLI_IMAGE} broker can-i-deploy ${PACT_ARGUMENTS} --to ${PACT_DEFAULT_ENV}"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, you need to use them as environment variable.

I have change the username and password below to be used as environment variables, you can do the same for the others if required.

```
stage('Can I Deploy to Dev') {
  agent none
  steps {
      sh 'docker run --rm ${PACT_CLI_IMAGE} broker can-i-deploy \
            --pacticipant ${APP_NAME} \
            --broker-base-url ${PACT_BROKER_URL} \
            --broker-username \$PACT_BROKER_BASIC_CREDENTIALS_USR \
            --broker-password \$PACT_BROKER_BASIC_CREDENTIALS_PSW \
            --version ${GIT_COMMIT}\
            --to ${PACT_DEFAULT_ENV}'
    }
}
```